# The value of $f'(n+1)-f'(1)$

Tags: functions

> Let $g(x) = e^{f(x)}$ where $g(x)$ is a differentiable function on $(0,\infty)$ such that $g(x+1) = (x+1)g(x)$. Then for $n = 1,2,3,\dots$,
>
> What is the value of $f'(n+1)-f'(1)$?

My try :

[image]

Comment: We have $$[(x+1)e^{f(x)}]' = e^{f(x)} + (x+1)f'(x)e^{f(x)}\\= e^{f(x)}(1 + f'(x) + xf'(x))$$There is no $f$ outside of the exponent, only $f'$.

Comment: Did you mean to ask for $f'(n+1)-f'(n)$?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/288417) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations, instead of uploading images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^{f(x+1)}=(x+1)e^{f(x)}$. So $ f(x+1)=\log (x+1) +f(x)$ and $ f(x+1)-f(x)=\log (x+1)$. Hence $f'(x+1)-f'(x)=\frac 1 {x+1}$. Put $x=n$ to get $f'(n+1)-f'(n)=\frac 1 {n+1}$.